# SmartGWT Post and redirect to URL

Tags: java, smartgwt

I'am trying to Redirect to an URL with Post Parameters. Therefor i am using a DynamicForm. My code Looks like:

```
DynamicForm postForm = DynamicForm();
postForm.setCanSubmit(true);
postForm.setMethod(FormMethod.POST);
postForm.setAction(URL_OF_WEBSITE + POST_PARAMS);
addChild(postForm);
```

ActionHandler of  a Button:

```
postForm.submitForm();
```

I debuged and the submitForm(); button is called. But nothing happened. 
Whats my mistake?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: **But nothing happened** can you explain it a bit more? What is not working? what are your expecting?

Comment: I expecting that the new window where i submiting will open in my browser.

Comment: Why don't you try `Window.open(URL_OF_WEBSITE + PARAMS,"","")`? where all the parameters are added in URL as query params. This will be a GET request.

Comment: Have a look [http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=3102](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=3102)

Comment: Thank You! With Window.open(), the new Window oppens with my Parameters. It is possible to do that with POST Request?

Comment: Look at this thread [How to send Post-Data to Window.open?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Google-Web-Toolkit/9BQFfiO6fzg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What JavaDoc of [DynamicForm#submitForm()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/DynamicForm.html#submitForm%28%29) says:

> this is used only in the very rare case that a form is used to submit data directly to a URL. Normal server contact is through [DataBound Component Methods](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/DataBoundComponentMethods.html).

In `SmartGWT` each `DynamicForm` is bound to a `DataSource` and you can call different methods on `DynamicForm` to add/delete/update the record in the database directly.

---

**I expecting that the new window where i submiting will open in my browser.**

If you want to call any URL then simply use `Window.open(servletURL+query-params,"","")` and pass the data in query string that is accepted as GET request by the Servlet.

Sample code:

```
String servletName = GWT.getModuleBaseURL().replace("/" + GWT.getModuleName(), "")
                                                        + "myServlet?key1=value1";
Window.open(servletName, "", "");
//Window.open(servletName, "_self", "");
```

Comment: Try `_self` as target in `Window.open()` to open on same page.